# socket.io-client causes ie11 to render blank

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer, socket.io, babeljs

I have a vue-cli app that is using socket.io-client to communicate to a socket server. The implementation works on all browsers but Internet Explorer 11. IE11 just renders an entirely blank white page. When I comment out `import io from 'socket.io-client`, IE 11 renders fine. This leads me to think that I'm missing some kind of babel pollyfill. I checked the github repo:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client and it looks like they're already using a promise pollyfill. Also vue has '@vue/app' as a preset by default, so I'm not sure what's going on.

EDIT:

I am using "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",

Comment: Did you see this [issue](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1328)?

Comment: Does it returns any kind of error? If possible for you then can you please try to provide any example that we can try to run with IE to check the results? It can help us to understand the  issue properly. Also inform us which version of socket.io-client you are using in this test?

Comment: Hey @Deepak-MSFT I'm currently using "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0". Let me create a boilerplate project and import it in to provide an example.

Comment: @StevenB. ahhh It didn't see that, but it sounds exactly like what i'm encountering. I'm also on the same version as the one in question in that thread. Let me revert back to v2.2.0 to see if it'll fix things.

Answer (score 0):

@Steven B. was spot on. His linked issue was in fact the reason why IE11 was rendering a blank screen.

I reverted back to v2.2.0 and it's working in IE11.

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1328

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.